# D3 updating x-y axes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am creating a small example to show dynamic axes update with button click. i am able to update the bars and the axes but the y axis spacing and bar alignment is not coming proper and somehow the bars seem to overlap for choice "R". I have tried a number of things but not able to pin point the issue. Kindly help me pin point the issue.

This is what i have done thus far and [link](https://dl.dropbox.com/s/nn22gs3evf5oyxi/Dummy.csv) to my dummy data:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style> /* set the CSS */

    path { 
        stroke: steelblue;
        stroke-width: 2;
        fill: none;
    }
    .bar {
        fill: skyblue;
    }

    .axis path,
    .axis line {
        fill: none;
        stroke: grey;
        stroke-width: 1;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
    .buttons-container {
              width: 520px;
              margin-bottom: 25px;
         }
         .button {
              float: left;
              margin-left: 10px;
              font-weight: lighter;
              cursor: pointer;
         }
         .selected {
              font-weight: bold;
         }
         .top-label {
              font-size: 13px;
              font-style: italic;
              text-transform: uppercase;
              float: left;
         }

         .axis-label {
              text-anchor: middle;
              font-size: 13px;
         }
         .x.axis line {
           fill: none;
           stroke: #000;
         }
         .x.axis text {
              font-size: 13px;
         }
         .axis path {
              display:none;
         }
         .y.axis line {
              display:none;
         }
    </style>
    <body>



    <!-- load the d3.js library -->    
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

    <script>

    // Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
        var margin = {top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 40, left: 50, padding: 5},
        width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 700 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
        var area = "P";

        var areas = ["P","Q", "R"];
        var x = d3.scaleLinear()
              .range([0, width]);
         var y = d3.scaleBand()
              .rangeRound([0, height], 0.1);

         var xAxis = d3.axisTop()
                       .scale(x);
         var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
                       .scale(y);

         var body = d3.select("body");
         var buttons = body.append("div")
              .attr("class", "buttons-container")
              .selectAll("div").data(areas)
           .enter().append("div")
              .text(function(d) { return d; })
              .attr("class", function(d) {
                   if(d == area)
                        return "button selected";
                   else
                        return "button";
              });


    function keys(d) {
              return d.subzone;
         }


    function render(){

    // Get the data
    d3.csv("data/Dummy.csv", function(error, data) {
        data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.subzone = d.subzone;
            d.zone = d.zone;
            d.pop = +d.pop;
        });
        data2= data.filter(function(element) {return element.zone == area});
        console.log(data2);
        // Scale the range of the data
        y.domain(data2.map(function(d){return d.subzone;}));
        x.domain([0, d3.max(data2, function(d) { return d.pop; })]);
        // Adds the svg canvas
        var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
            .attr("transform", 
                  "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        var barGroup = svg.append("g").attr("class", "bar")
                                      .attr("width",width)
                                      .attr("height", height);

        var bars = barGroup.selectAll("rect").data(data2, keys)
                           .enter().append("rect")
                           .attr("x", 0)
                           .attr("y",function(d){return y(d.subzone);})
                           .attr("width", function(d){return x(d.pop);})
                           .attr("height",y.bandwidth()-20 )

        // Add the X Axis
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis);

        // Add the Y Axis
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .call(yAxis);
        buttons.on("click", function(zone) {


                   d3.select(".selected")
                        .classed("selected", false);
                   d3.select(this)
                        .classed("selected", true);
                   area = zone;
                   popData = data.filter(function(element) {return element.zone == area});
                   y.domain(popData.map(function(d){return d.subzone;}));
                   x.domain([0, d3.max(popData, function(d) { return d.pop; })])
                   console.log(popData);
                   var ba = barGroup.selectAll("rect").data(popData);

                   ba.transition()
                        .duration(500)
                        .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.pop); });

                    ba.enter().append("rect") .attr("x", 0)
                           .attr("y",function(d){return y(d.subzone);})
                           .attr("width", function(d){return x(d.pop);})
                           .attr("height",y.bandwidth()-20 );
                     ba.exit().remove();
    svg.select(".y.axis").transition().duration(1500).call(yAxis);
                        svg.select(".x.axis").transition().duration(1500).call(xAxis);



});

});

    };


    render();

    </script>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using d3.js version 4, the [magic of implicitly merging the enter() and update selections no longer applies](https://medium.com/@mbostock/what-makes-software-good-943557f8a488#79ab). You need to change this line:

```
ba.enter().append("rect") .attr("x", 0)
```

...to this:

```
ba.enter().append("rect").merge(ba).attr("x", 0)
```

See [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Gl2nVef5ZPjGgofA0lgY?p=preview) which I created to debug/test. I have also "fixed" the bar transitions - you were changing the width in a transition then overriding that without a transition - but note that there is no [object constancy](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/constancy/) between the bars, the transition is just pretty. It might be better to just fade out the exiting bars and fade in the entering ones, and use a data key to make sure the transitioning bars are actually representing the same data.

Comment: may i ask what change will be good for transitions as you mentioned

Comment: Hi owen..can you please share how object constancy can be implemented in this context. Shall I use keys function in the implementation of var ba..? Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, that's right; but since there are no bars in common, it's the same as removing all and adding all.

Comment: Thanks owen..may I ask ur inputs on another question I asked yesterday regarding d3 nesting and object traversal.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39585265/d3-nesting-and-object-traversal